# How can I load a package when I get this error?

Tags: r, shiny, package

when i use

```
library(ggExtra)
```

I get the following error message

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggExtra’:
> .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'shiny', details:
> call: NULL
> error: invalid version specification ‘1,5’

I use shiny 1.7.1, ggExtra 0.9,  R 4.3.1.

I get the some error message when I try to load **shiny** and **radiant.data** packages

I'm looking to understand the error and to a solution. Thanks in advance, any kind of help is appriciated.

Comment: Are you trying to run shinyapp locally or on the cloud, for example: shinyapps.io ?

Comment: @zx8754 I don't know exactly what shinyapps.io is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try remove and reinstall the packages with `dependencies = TRUE` by using this code:

```
remove.packages(c("ggExtra", "shiny", "radiant.data"))
install.packages('ggExtra', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages('shiny', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages('radiant.data', dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggExtra)
library(shiny)
library(radiant.data)
```

Output when running `library(ggExtra)`:

```
Attaching package: ‘ggExtra’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    runExample
```